# How to establish a client to client Voice Call over socket in android

Tags: android, sockets, voip, serversocket

I am planning to add a direct serverless point to point voice transfer ability to my application, from my thoughts each client needs a server socket(?) and client socket(?) to establish connection on demand, rest must be same like writing voice to file but instead writing to (socket?) on tcp . but since its a quite long shot, I need some more help about it, like can 2 sockets send and receive on the same time? Or more importantly can socket keep reading and update the output at the time? Or is there any better way? any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://github.com/DeanThomson/android-udp-audio-chat

I think this is exactly you required

Comment: Only-link answers are bad. You should give some more info on the link or library itself. Just saying. :)

Comment: dude, im studying on that library since noon, it uses InetAdress for now, which means they must be on a local host like wifi or some thing, woudle it be possible to use any thing else instead inet adress ? for example use a tcp socket and a server socket on the client?

Comment: I didn't understand your query perfectly.Anyway , both caller & receiver must be on the same network to establish communication(both have same network address : 3rd field in the IP address) . The provided application works with LAN connections.Audio data packets are transferred as UDP packets & it's less reliable.Presence of noise may interrupt your communication.Have you test this application in your phone ?

Comment: @Don> I have two phones. On one phone (incoming) voice is clear, on another phone (incoming voice) is only noise - what may be the issue?